# getParameter returns null from Method get

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, get

I'm tryring to get an id from url but getParameter return null
this is how I'm sending the id in the url (tool.jsp):

```
<a href="http://localhost:8080/Projectpfeweb/executetool.jsp?id=${l.tool_id}" class="btn btn-info" role="button">Execute</a>
```

this the doGet method where I want the id value

```
 protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException,IOException
{
      ToolDAO dao=new ToolDAO();

    String id= req.getParameter("id");

    Tool t=dao.getToolById(Integer.parseInt(id));
      String first = req.getParameter("first");
     byte[] bytes = first.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
     first= new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
   if(first!=null)
   {
    String [] input=first.split(" ");
      System.out.println("input"+input[0]);
      EXEJAVA exe=new EXEJAVA();
      FileRead f=new FileRead();

      f.writeinputfile(input);
       ArrayList l=exe.executetool(t.getTool_path_exe());

       req.setAttribute("l",l);
       req.setAttribute("first", first);
       req.getRequestDispatcher("executetool.jsp").forward(req, res);
}
```

and this is the form (executetool.jsp)

```
 <form accept-charset="UTF-8" name="form" action="executetool" method="get">

<div class="centre">
<div class="row">
<div class="inline-div">
  <label for="ta1">Text in Latin script</label>
<textarea cols="60" rows="15" id="first" name="first" class="inline-
txtarea">${first}</textarea>
</div>
&nbsp;
<div class="inline-div">
<input type="button" value="Clear" onclick="javascript:eraseText();"> 
  </div>
  &nbsp;
  <div class="inline-div">
    <label for="ta2" >Text in Arabic script</label>
    <textarea cols="60" rows="15" id="second" name="second" class="inline-
    txtarea"><c:forEach items="${l}" var="s">${s}&nbsp;</c:forEach>
    </textarea>
     </div>
     </div>
   </div>

     </form>
```

Since it's method get the url keeps changing everytime the page is refreshed and so the "id=something" part gets replaced by the value of the two text areas that I have in the form what sould I do to always keep that part in the url?

Comment: Use hidden input to ID attribute or set the ID to session and u can access to the parameter from everywhere.

Comment: the hidden input solution didn't work because again if the page is refreshed the value gets lost , as for the session I'm not familiar with it so could you please give me more details?

Comment: IN  JSP  : <%String username = (String)request.getAttribute("un");
session.setAttribute("UserName", username);%>

Comment: IN SERVLET OR ETC.  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    String username = (String)request.getAttribute("un");
    session.setAttribute("UserName", username);
}

Comment: didn't work I got null

Answer (score 1):

Place a hidden field instead

```
<input type='hidden' name='id' value='${l.tool_id}'>
```

Then use input type submit for the button, not a generic `<a>` tag as that won't submit the form unless you have a javascript code somewhere that will submit the form for you.

You can also place the id in the `action` attribute of the form.

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" name="form" action="executetool?id=${l.tool_id}" method="get">
```

Comment: I edited my question ; where I send the id and the form with the get method are not the same jsp pages

Comment: @OumaymaBouzidi I see. Perhaps the ID is truly null to begin with if that's the case. Have you tried inspecting the `<a>` element to see if it truly has an id?

Comment: when I click the button I can see it in the url so no it's not null